# Passing firebase.initializeApp as a prop into my Router component - React-Native

Tags: firebase, react-native

This is my first time using firebase and I was wondering how can I pass my `const firebaseApp` into the `<Provider / <Router/>` component, or what is the best way to do this? I'm trying to pass it to my **MainPage** component thats after my **Router** component.  Cheers!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import Router from './Router';


class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
      apiKey: 'xxx',
      authDomain: 'xxx',
      databaseURL: 'xxx',
      storageBucket: 'xxx',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxx'
  };
  // firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router initializeApp={this.initApp} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```